# Redirecting to a List View is not working: "URL doesn't exist anymore"

Tags: visualforce, list-view, outputlink

I am trying to redirect to a specific List View on top part of the application, but I am not getting how to amend the issue "There is no URL for this", so, I hope to find here someone who can help me.

Mi Visualforce looks like this. This is the part where I am trying to redirect to the top and not within my Visualforce component:

```
<apex:component access="global" controller="RelatedLists" allowDML="true">

  <apex:attribute name="accountIdValue" type="String" description="This is the Id of the account" assignTo="{!accountId}" access="global" />
   <apex:form id="RelatedLists">
      <apex:outputPanel id="redirectPanel" >
           <apex:outputText rendered="{!shouldRedirect}">
                <script type="text/javascript">
                     window.top.location.href = '{!url}';
                </script>
           </apex:outputText>
      </apex:outputPanel>

This is the part in my Visualforce component where I am invoking the method to redirect to the specific list view:

    <apex:outputLink id="linkGotoList" value="GotoSolInfoList">Ir a lista »</apex:outputLink>
```

This is the method in the Apex controller, which should handle the redirection:

```
public PageReference GotoSolInfoList() {

shouldRedirect = true;
Pagereference url = new Pagereference('/a0B?fcf=00B3E000000uGXb');
url.setredirect(true);
return url;

}
```

What I get is this:

[image]

So, "URL doesn't exist anymore".
Any ideas, suggestions how can I amend this issue?

Update

Thank you very much, Yamsi. It works if I put "/a0B?fcf=00B3E000000uGXb" directly in the outputlink tag, but you stay within the Visualforce component and that is not what I need and want. When I click on the GoToList, this should not only redirect me to the corresponding list view, but outside the Visualforce component, I mean on the top tab. I don't know if this is clear, I am trying to explain it clearly.

When you click on a normal related list, on Got To List, this leads your to the top tab. That doesn't happen with my code unfortunately and this is what I want to achieve. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you use `apex:commandLink` instead of `apex:outputlink` and call the controller method.

```
<apex:commandLink id="linkGotoList" value="GotoSolInfoList" id="theCommandLink" action="{!GotoSolInfoList}">
Ir a lista »
</apex:commandLink>
```

> **apex:commandLink**
>
> A link that executes an action defined by a controller, and then either refreshes the current page, or navigates to a different page based on the PageReference variable that is returned by the action. An  component must always be a child of an  component.

**action method:**

> The action method invoked by the AJAX request to the server. Use merge-field syntax to reference the method. For example, action="{!save}" references the save() method in the controller. If an action isn't specified, the page simply refreshes. Note that command links associated with the save, edit, or delete actions in a standard controller are rendered only if the user has the appropriate permissions. Likewise, command links associated with the edit and delete actions are rendered only if a record is associated with the page.

Answer (score 0):

you have used a static text in the value part of [outputlink](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_compref_outputLink.htm) which is not going to work.

don't need to invoke an apex method to get the url as a page reference for a simple redirection.

we can directly use the url in the value attribute like this.

```
<apex:outputLink value="/a0B?fcf=00B3E000000uGXb" id="theLink">Your List View Name</apex:outputLink>
```